# how to load jffs2 image in mpc8309twr

Tags: linux, filesystems, bootloader

I am trying to load the jffs2 filesystem through uboot in powerpc mpc8309twr board, while uncompressing the kernel image it is showing

**Wrong Ramdisk Image Format**

**Ramdisk image is corrupt or invalid**

and i am having the bootargs & bootcmd

**bootargs=root=/dev/mtdblock4 rootfstype=jffs2 rw console=ttys0,115200**

**bootcmd=bootm fe100000 fe800000 fe0e0000**

below is the case, I am getting

```
U-Boot 2010.06-00077-gd1e0776 (Dec 27 2011 - 19:51:03) MPC83XX

Reset Status:

CPU:   e300c3, MPC8309E, Rev: 1.1 at 400 MHz, CSB: 133.333 MHz
Board: Freescale MPC8309_twr
I2C:   ready
SPI:   ready
DRAM:  128 MiB
FLASH: 32 MiB
Firmware 'Microcode version 0.0.0 for MPC8309 r1.0' for 8309 V1.0
QE: uploading microcode 'Microcode for MPC8309 r1.0'
In:    vga
Out:   vga
Err:   vga
MMC:  FSL_ESDHC: 0
Net:   FSL UEC0, FSL UEC1
USB RESET
Register 10011 NbrPorts 1
USB EHCI 1.00
The USB ULPI VIEWPORT reg  value is 40000001
The USB ULPI VIEWPORT reg  value is 8
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at fe100000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-2.6.33.7.2-rt30
   Image Type:   PowerPC Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    2000340 Bytes = 1.9 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
Wrong Ramdisk Image Format
Ramdisk image is corrupt or invalid
```

can anyone share the info, why this is showing ramdisk?

Comment: *"why this is showing ramdisk?"* -- Because you specified an initrd exists at RAM address 0xfe800000 in the **bootm** command.   A JFFS2 can only be used when installed to a flash chip.  Assuming that you have actually written the JFFS2 image to the proper MTD partition, then the **bootargs** (aka kernel command line) is sufficient to specify the rootfs to the kernel.  Therefore no initrd should be specified in the **bootm** command.  Use a hyphen/dash to designate that there is no initrd, e.g. `bootm fe100000 - fe0e0000`

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for reply, okay now i changed the bootcmd, its loading jffs2.